# How to avoid creating multiple data in elasticsearch using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

While sending data into elasticsearch using logstash, same data stream is getting repeated many times. How to avoid this ?

Defining "repeating":
When we send one stream of data, for example - "key1":"name1", I am seeing multiple lines of this same data in elastic search.

Comment: Please provide more info into what you're doing, eventually your logstash configuration and some examples on what you mean by "multiple data"

Comment: In configuration file, we kept a port open which keeps listening to data continuously.  Also we made changes to elasticearch template file. Because we want to have .raw field. We found this problem after giving that .raw. This is the ES template file - http://pastebin.com/06XHpShK

Comment: It should not have changed anything. Also what do you mean by repeated?

Comment: And when adding information, it is best to update the question instead of just putting in the comments

Comment: Sure baudsp. I made relevant edits in my question.